# Función substring() dentro de Java

Tags: java

Necesito terminar este ejercicio:

> Realizar un programa que simule el funcionamiento de un dispositivo RS232, este
> tipo de dispositivo lee cadenas enviadas por el usuario. Las cadenas deben llegar
> con un formato fijo: tienen que ser de un máximo de 5 caracteres de largo, el primer
> carácter tiene que ser X y el último tiene que ser una O.
> Las secuencias leídas que respeten el formato se consideran correctas, la
> secuencia especial “&&&&&” marca el final de los envíos (llamémosla FDE), y toda
> secuencia distinta de FDE, que no respete el formato se considera incorrecta.
> Al finalizar el proceso, se imprime un informe indicando la cantidad de lecturas
> correctas e incorrectas recibidas.

Al realizar mi programa logro la primer verificación de los 5 caracteres y de la salida "&&&&&"  ,
pero cuando comparo la primer letra y la última la condición no se cumple.

La condición es la siguiente:

```
if ("o".equals(palabra.substring(0))  && "x".equals(palabra.substring(4))){
                   
    correcto=correcto+1 ;}
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Revisa la documentación de [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). Estás comparando una cadena de 1 caracter con otra cadena de más de 1 caracter, es claro que ambas nunca serán iguales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función substring() en Java devuelve una cadena de caracteres y puede recibir uno o dos parámetros.

El primer parámetro indica la posición inicial y el segundo la posición final a partir de los cuales se construirá la subcadena a devolver.

En el caso de que solo se especifique un parámetro, este identificará la posición del carácter inicial y la posición final será el final de la cadena.

Por tanto, en tu caso, cuando estas haciendo

```
palabra.substring(0)
```

Estas devolviendo la palabra entera y por tanto no se cumple la condición de ser igual a “o”.

Cuando haces

```
palabra.substring(4)
```

Estas devolviendo desde la quinta posición hasta el final de la palabra.

Comment: entonces tendria que ser la primera (0,0) y la segunda(4,4)?

Comment: primera (0,1) y la segunda(4,5)

Comment: muchas gracias no puedo darte un upvote porque no tengo 15 ptos de reputacion pero muchas gracias

Comment: creo que puedes dar la respuesta por valida